# Named connections all over the world

Tags: macos, network-scanners

I just started working for a small business and run their server. The entire thing is on macOS, and I've been monitoring my network lately due to some weird things in a few log files.

I've come across something called `named` which makes connections both UDP and TCP all across the world. From what I've gathered, the `named` service has something to do with my DNS, however, that doesn't make much sense because I don't have anybody working overseas, or trying to connect from different countries.

[image]

My question to all of you would be, is this a reason for me to be alarmed?

Comment: named is really just bind for mac as far as I know. And the way the DNS protocol works, I can think of a few reasons why it would connect out (replicating/renewal of dns records to name one, these records will be requested from the Authoritative DNS servers). Best would be to check the individual Remote IP's to verify if these are actual DNS servers if you're really suspicious.

Comment: @Nomad Well in the last 20 minutes there has been over 100 different IP addresses and over 80 different host names connecting to my server from about 10 different countries. I'm not an expert, but I don't think that's normal

Comment: It is for DNS. Don't make strong statements on systems you havens understood!

Comment: @MarcusMüller Which strong statement are you referring to?

Comment: "I don't think that's normal"

Comment: That depends, really. Consider every DNS request a possible connection (if caching isn't enabled or the hostnames aren't cached). Visiting 1 single website can lead to multiple dns requests, not to speak of how loud some services are. If everything passes through that machine, reasonable is a very scalable property :-) I would start by verifying Named's configuration so that only those who should be able to access it, can, before worrying too much.

Comment: @Nomad awh, the caching is what got me thinking. I refreshed my cache yesterday because it was overflowing with useless stuff. I've been taking your advice and checking the individual IP addresses. It seems about 99% of them run to a DNS server there's still a few that are weird but I can figure those out. I appreciate your help!

Comment: Np, that's what stackexchange is for! I've thrown it all in an answer for others to find if they have the same question :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**named - MacOS**

`named` can be considered to be the `bind` service for Mac, which all comes down to being a DNS server.

**DNS**

A DNS server makes requests to other DNS servers on the internet if it needs to turn a domain name into an IP address, and it doesn't know about that domain name.

A solution to this is caching, which stores addresses and hostnames, so your server doesn't have to make all requests at the corresponding servers.

**Connections**

This means that for every domain that has to be resolved, and isn't known to the cache, a connection (TCP) will be made, or a packet will be sent and received (UDP) by another server.

Visiting a single website with all the JS frameworks and possibly (but rarely) externally hosted images, can result in multiple DNS requests.

There are a lot of programs that have to connect to a server for licensing issues, feeds, ... which also have name resolution.

Some software is known to use `getHostByName()` as a connection test to big sites, or their own DNS servers, because it will check internet connection and UDP is a super fast.
(For Example: Huawei's EMUI(Android) makes a DNS Request to Baidu when booting)

**But it's not all good**

Before panicking, consider what I wrote above, and verify your configurations to see that connections are legit. You could also use whois to check if the connections are actually towards and from legitimate DNS servers.

If they're not all good, or you keep getting high traffic outside office hours etc, consider the fact that misconfiguration of DNS servers and firewall rules can lead to UDP flood attacks and the like.

Another totally paranoid thing to consider after all above failed is that someone activated malware on your system that hides as the `named` service, but that is completely out of consideration before being absolutely certain about firewall and configuration.